# Presto query : concat multiple rows into one string

Tags: sql, concatenation, presto

I have a table: my_table

```
customer_id
-------------
 2156
 6781
 3145
 1235
 9874
```

I want the output to be one concat string with comma like: `2156, 6781, 3145, 1235, 9874`
So far I export the table and using python to do it. I am wondering could I do it directly in Presto query? Thanks!

Comment: I was going to answer, but the helpful answers in the duplicate link already answer your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think Presto has a string aggregation.  Instead, aggregate as an array and convert to a string:

```
select array_join(array_agg(customer_id), ', ') as customer_ids
from my_table
```